# Colorize button in css

Tags: html, css, button

I found a button code so I used it. After that I saw that the button was completely transparent I learned how to colorize its text but not the background.

Can you assist?

**The Code is:**

```css
.my_content_container a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    height: 2.5em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    width: 5em;       
    text-decoration: none;       
}
```

```html
<div class="my_content_container">
    <a href="/my/link/location/">Go to my link location</a>
</div>
```

Comment: do you find anything useful when you google "set div background color"?

Comment: Wasn't the question "coloring in JavaScript"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `background` property  `background-color` to change the background color.

Example:

```css
.my_content_container a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    height: 2.5em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    width: 5em;       
    text-decoration: none;  
    background-color: red;     
}
```

```html
<div class="my_content_container">
    <a href="/my/link/location/">Go to my link location</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-color` property in your css rule:

```
.my_content_container a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    height: 2.5em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    width: 5em;       
    text-decoration: none; 
    background-color: #fbca8e;  /* <- Here  */    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I colorize my button in JavaScript?

Use `style.backgroundColor` property.

```js
document.querySelector(".my_content_container > a").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```css
.my_content_container a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  width: 5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_content_container">
  <a href="/my/link/location/">Go to my link location</a>
</div>
```